# xaml WPF universal Storyboard Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, blend

I currently am building a windows app using DotNet 4.6.2 / C# / Wpf ( Xaml ) and the Prism Framework.

I was wondering if anyone here can help me with my "situation". I would like to trigger a storyboard from a button which is in a seperate "view". To explain in more detail I have created a graphic:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljccj.png)

I have to add that I have no experience whatsoever with C# and am a visual designer working in Blend with Xaml :/ so I hope I dont get flamed..

I hope someone can help..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned Prism you can use ***EventAggregator*** to communicate.
you can do something like this.First define your pubsubevent

```
public class MyEvents : PubSubEvent<object>
{
    public MyEvents();
}
```

In your View you have your button and in the click event

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyEvents myEvents = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvents>();
        myEvents.Publish("yourparameter");
    }
```

And subscribe to that event where ever you wanted to manipulate it.For example

```
public ViewModel()
{
        MyEvents myEvents = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvents>();
        myEvents.Subscribe(MethodName, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
}

void MethodName(object parameter)
{
   // Handle here
}
```

This is of the method how you can do.

Comment: First off, thanks allot for the reply!, is there any way I can contact you personally on this matter ? I would love to show you what I have and get your thoughts in on things I might need to read / learn